# How to add Global MongoDB connection String to C# Project

Tags: c#, mongodb, database-connection, connection-string, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using my MongoDB database to store some documents for my project. The driver version for MongoDB I am using is 2.12.2.
How I am using my Mongo connection for my Operations is like this,

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
     <add key="MongoDBDatabase" value="TestDB" />
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MongoConnection" connectionString="myconnnection/db?retryWrites=true"/>
      </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**DBConnection.cs**

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyProj.DataAccess.Implementations
{
    internal class DBConnection
    {
        public static string MongoDBConnectionString { get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoConnection"].ConnectionString; } }

        public static string MongoDBdatabase { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDBDatabase"].ToString(); } }
    }
}
```

**UserDAL.cs**

```
namespace MyProj.DataAccess.Implementations
{
    public class UserDAL: IUserDAL
    {
public static string database = DBConnection.MongoDBdatabase;
public List<UserTbl> GetAll()
        {
            var con = new MongoClient(DBConnection.MongoDBConnectionString);
            var db = con.GetDatabase(database);
            var collection = db.GetCollection<UserTbl>("UserTbls");
var users=collection.AsQueryable().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is I need to call the connection globally  like from singleton. So that only a single connection is open for multiple requests. How can I do that ?

Comment: the only option is to store mongoClient as singleton

Comment: how can I do that ? Is there a reference I can follow ?@dododo

Comment: it's not related to mongodb and dependent on your application. For asp.net + DI you can check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods

Comment: or as a "dirty" workaround, you can store mongoclient just in a static property. However there is another option that I missed above, if you use the same connectionString (and don't use clusterConfigurator), you can just create a new MongoClient each time when you need this (for appdomain), each new mongoClient will reuse the previously created underlying machinery including connections

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to you to config your mongodb client with best practices like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp/)
you can define your mongodb as singlton  but be aware you should use async methods , I prefer you to use `ConcurrentQueue` and its methods

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).